# Arf-Brown-Kervaire invariant and a surjective map $G \to Pin^-$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, cobordism, spin-geometry

We know that the Arf-Brown-Kervaire (abk) invariant is a bordism invariant of
$$
\Omega_2^{Pin^-}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}/(8\mathbb{Z}),
$$
where the $\mathbb{Z}/(8\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by a 2-manifold $M^2$ generator, such as 
$$
\mathbb{RP}^2,
$$
or the invariant $$\exp( 2 \pi i (k/8) \int_{M^2} \; \text{(abk)}),$$
with $k \in \mathbb Z_8$

> - My question: Does there exist any surjective $$G \to Pin^-,$$
>     such that it is a surjective map $G \to Pin^-$, and the 
>     Arf-Brown-Kervaire invariant $\exp( 2 \pi i (k/8) \int_{M^2} \; \text{(abk)})$ at the even integer $k$ of $\Omega_2^{Pin^-}(pt)$ becomes a trivial bordism invariant, under pullback, evaluated at $$\Omega_2^{G}?$$
>     Namely the corresponding invariant for $\Omega_2^{G}$ on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (at the even integer $k$) becomes 1. (i.e. a trivial group element.)

p.s. It is obviously  possible to find $G$, if the $G \to Pin^-$ is an injective instead of surjective map. Say, we can take $G=Spin \to Pin^-,$ then $\Omega_2^{Spin}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z})$ is obviously trivial, when we map back from any even integer $k$ in $\Omega_2^{Pin^-}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}/(8\mathbb{Z})$ to $k \mod 2$ as $0$ in $$\Omega_2^{Spin}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z}).$$

Comment: The notation $\Omega_3^G$ is almost always used to denote cobordism classes of 3-manifolds with $G$-structure, rather than 2-manifolds (so it's more common to write $\Omega_2^{\mathrm{Pin}^-}$, $\Omega_2^{\mathrm{Spin}}$, etc.).

Comment: What restrictions do you place on the G? For example let $G = Spin \times_{Pin^-} P(Pin^-)$ where $P(H)$ is the free path space on $H$ with pointwise multiplication. The fiber product uses restriction to one end of a path. Restriction to the other end of the path gives a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $Pin^-$. But $G \simeq Spin$ and so $G$-bordism is the same as $Spin$-bordism.